# Output of two components on one page in joomla 2.5,

Tags: joomla, components

I want to show the output of two components on one page in joomla 2.5, anyone knows how to do it plz tell me

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't sound like you have even tried researching your problem/request. I went searched what you needed in Google and found a forum thread, and someone had posted this link:

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/embed-a-include/8741

It's a plugin that allows you to include components using a syntax such as:

```
{component url='' }
```

Hope this helps, but in future please do a little research.

Comment: thank you Lodder , i tried this before posting question here but it didn't work :(